# Computation of density function

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Suppose (W i
t )t>0, i ∈ {1, 2} are two independent Wiener processes. Let $\tau = inf (t > 0 : |W_{t}2
 | = a) $ for
a > 0. Show that the random variable W 1
τ has a density
f (x) = (2a cosh(πx/(2a)))−1.

I do not know how to solve this exercise

I think you can  use that $f(t)=(\E \Phi(t/\sqrt{\tau} ))'=\E
(1/\sqrt{\tau})(1/\sqrt{2\pi})\exp(-t^2/(2\tau))$
And computing this expectancy knowing the definition of $\tau$. But I dont know how this can follow...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.